# Doctrine annotaion to return null records in child table

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I want to return all child records and those records that have null foreign key's value by using doctrine annotation.
This is user entity:

```
....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DeliveryMethods", mappedBy="owner")
     */
    private $delivery_methods;

....
```

And here is delivery method entity(table with child rows):

```
....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="delivery_methods")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner", nullable=true)
     */
    private $owner;
....
```

What change I need to make in the annotations?

Thanks

Comment: If a delivery_method has owner = null it isn't binded to any owner ... So there is no owner with a null child.

Comment: I know and I want to return all `owner_id=null` records with other result, I mean something like `owner_id=x OR owner_id=null`  while `x` is a `user_id`.

Comment: The annotation is meant to return related entities. Nothing else.

Comment: For that, you would have to write a custom repository method.

Comment: And Should I rewrite all joins? Is there anyway to use default relations (joins) except this one and I change this one only?

Comment: You haven't to rewrite any join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a new `repository` class and add something like below :

```
class DeliveryMethodsRepository extends EntityRepository {

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $owner
     * @return type
     */
    public function getOwnerAssociatedOrOrphanEntities($ownerId) {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("dm")
            ->andWhere("dm.owner = :owner OR dm.owner = NULL")
            ->setParameter("owner", $ownerId);

        return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

And call this method from `DeliveryMethod` Repository from `Controller`.

Please note : You can also write custom `query builder` inside any Controller method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup, finally I had to use something like this. thanks.